# Добавить строку через форму в .txt файл загружаемый на сервер

Tags: php, form, upload

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы пользователь мог добавить строку в загружаемый файл, нашла такой вариант:

```
$fp = fopen('загружаемый файл', 'r+');
fwrite($fp, 'добавляемая строчка'."\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```

не понимаю как его интегрировать в такой код:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload_process'])){

    $allowed_filetypes = array('.txt');

    $filename = $_FILES['filename']['name'];

    $ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

    if(strlen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']) < 1)
    die('Сперва укажите файл для загрузки.<br><a href="upload.php">Попробовать еще раз</a>');

    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
    die('Данный формат не поддерживается.<br><a href="upload.php">Попробовать еще раз</a>');

    if(filesize($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']) > 1024*1024*5)
    die('Файл превышает допустимые значения.<br><a href="upload.php">Попробовать еще раз</a>');

    if(!is_writable(ROOT_DIR.ARTICLE_DIR))
    die('Директория закрыта от записи. обратитесь к системному администратору.');

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'],ROOT_DIR.ARTICLE_DIR . $filename))
    die('Ваш фаил успешно загружен.<br><a href="upload.php">Загрузить ещё</a>');
    else
    echo 'При загрузке возникли ошибки.<br><a href="upload.php">Попробовать еще раз</a>';
    }
```

форма:

```
<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='30000'>
    <p>Название статьи:</p>
    <input type='text' name='userfilename' placeholder='text'><br>
    <p>Файл</p>
    <div id="btn">
    <label for="files">Мой текст</label>
    </div>
    <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type='file' name='filename' class='select_file'><br>
    <button class='upload' name='upload_process' class='login_button'>Добавить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: что собственно не работает то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все проcто. перед

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'],ROOT_DIR.ARTICLE_DIR . $filename)
```

впишите

```
$fp = fopen('$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']', 'r+');
fwrite($fp, 'добавляемая строчка'."\r\n");
fclose($fp);
```